# as3: draw circle with a hole in it using only actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay so basically I want to draw a circle in as3 that has a 'hole' in it (like a donut). Something like this, but without the outlines:

http://www.steel.ie/DugganSteel/Pictures/Hollow-circle.gif

This doesn't work:

```
SPRITE.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
SPRITE.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);
SPRITE.graphics.endFill();
SPRITE.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,5);
```

I mean this seems like it'd be simple but I can't find any information on it. I should also mention that I'm trying to only draw 3/4 of the circle, like 3/4 of donut. So I was planning on drawing a transparent circle and square over the original circle, I know this seems kinda of weird since you'd expect something transparent to show whats underneath it.

Answer (score 10):

Its actually really simple. See the following code:

```
var p:Point = new Point(100, 100);
graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
graphics.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 100);
graphics.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 50);
```

Intersections cancel each other out until you call `endFill`

Goodluck!

Comment: only thing I don't understand is, why do intersections cancel each other?

Comment: I found a useful link : http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/

Comment: That's a good read, it focuses on the new drawing API though, so watch out for that!

Comment: This is great - but it doesn't actually work if you're drawing less than a full donut, which is what he asked about. Would be great to figure out an easy way to do that (i'm not having much luck).

Comment: @danjp solution is correct; only set a line style and do not use beginFill

Answer (score 2):

You can just make the line thickness the desired donut width and avoid using beginFill
set graphics.lineStyle
To make it only go 3/4 of the way around you could use curveTo to draw the 3 quarters.

Answer (score 1):

The above method by Tyler works, however if an easier way to do it is to simply begin drawing the inner circle first. Basically Flash doesn't actually fill in the color until you call `endFill()` (again as mentioned by Tyler), so you start drawing on the inner circle, then the outer circle then on `endFill()` Flash fills in the gap.

```
SPRITE.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
SPRITE.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,5);
SPRITE.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);
SPRITE.graphics.endFill();
```

Hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: I don't see what's easier about this, you just flipped two lines around. Its exactly the same thing, you draw two shapes and they are intersected leaving the result.

Comment: Yeah your right, shouldn't have used the word easier. There the same

Answer (score 0):

Introduction to Flash drawing API, will help you understand a bit more :

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/